# ReactJS- Youtube Data API request error 400

Tags: reactjs, axios, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-400

I was using YouTube Data API. I did set up the parameters but when opening network from developer tools it is showing error: 'Required parameter:part'

axios code-

```
import axios from 'axios';

const KEY='[my key]'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    params:
    {
        part:'snippet',
        maxResults:5,
        key: KEY
    }
})
```

The callback function which is sending API request

```
termSearch= (term)=>
    {   
        console.log(term)
        youtube.get('/search',{
            params:
            {
                q:term
            }
        })
```

I expected to receive the JSON response but console is showing-
Error:GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=asdas 400

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there is an open issue on [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190) where request parameters are not getting merged with instance parameters. So your `params` object from your `axios.create(...)` are not being used properly in your callback.

Maybe you could try downgrading `Axios` to version: `0.18.1` until a fix has been patched in? This seems to be the workaround used by others at this particular instance in time.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In call back function before `q` parameter add all the parameter of Param code from Axios code, your call back function should be like:

```
termSearch= (term)=>
    {   
        console.log(term)
        youtube.get('/search',{
            params:
            {
             part:'snippet',
        maxResults:5,
        key: 'your_Api_KEY'
                q:term
            }
        })
```

and don't change your Axios code. It should be like this

```
import axios from 'axios';
const KEY='[my key]'
export default axios.create({
        baseURL:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
        params:
        {
            part:'snippet',
            maxResults:5,
            key: KEY
        }
    })
```